# Use IIS as local web server to debug in my visual studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, debugging, iis

I've an asp.net MVC website which use somme DLL that work only in 32 bits or only in 64 bits(sql lite).

Since our server are running in 64 bits, I would like to run all my code in 64 bits. The problem is that the Visual studio development server is running in 32 bits in all case.

So I come to use a Local IIS Web server.

The problem is that with an asp.net **MVC** website, it's mandatory to have the website at the root of the URL.

So I wish to have something like "mywebsite.lo"(with a entry in my hosts file) or "localhost:9999" as project url.

But if I try to put this, when I create the virtual directory, I got this error:
*Unable to create the virtual directory. Could not find the server 'mywebsite.lo' on the local machine. Creating a virtual directory is only supported on the local IIS server.*

So I created myself the website with the correct binding responding to 'mywebsite.lo'. Now if I click on Create Virtual Directory, I got a successfull message. If But when I run the website, I got a message saying : *Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not configured correctly. See help for common configuration errors. Running the web page outside of the debugger may provide further information.*

Comment: It is not mandatory to have an asp.net mvc website at the root of the site.  Where did you hear that?

Comment: Last time I tried I had problem with routing.

Comment: Well, whatever problem you had, it was not because MVC doesn't allow it.  More than likely, your problem was that you did not set the subfolder to be an application in IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a dummy mistake: The application pool was in .Net 2.x :/

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug in visual studio with a local IIS, then Visual Studio must be running as an administrator, are you doing that?